# Apache beam BigQuery view

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

In GCP BigQuery, you can create a view of a table. Documentation here: `https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views`.

I would like to know whether it is possible to create a view in BigQuery via Apache Beam, it is not in the documenation `https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/` if so.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a BQ View using Apache Beam. But you can read data represented by a View using a [Query](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fea8fa51f9ca43410db4c77d8f92de10cee2f7e6/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L684).